# React JS setInterval to API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I want to make a call to an API once an hour, every hour, using setInterval, how would I go about implementing that?

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(fullURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      // console.log(responseJson);
      const resultyt = responseJson.items.map(obj => "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + obj.id.videoId);
      this.setState({resultyt});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

the API call is stored inside a const called fullURL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap that up in a function that can be called many times, then simply use setInterval:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => this.loadData(), 3600000);
    this.loadData(); // also load one immediately
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}

loadData() {
    fetch(fullURL).then(...);
}
```

Comment: @baileyhaldwin - setInterval on its own will call the provided function forever. Because you probably don't want that to happen after the component goes away, you stop it by calling clearInterval.

Comment: setInterval is problematic, setTimeout is better approach.
it is problematic because of edge scenarios that it will take long time to the server to respond, and before the server responded, another call to server will be sent because of the setinterval.
instead: inside your api call onsuccess and onerror cal a settimeout. so this will ensure that only when api call returns another one will be fired in xx seconds. and you wont have potential multiple calls to server